# Setting a Quiz System

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I'm developing a MCQs based Quiz system where my goal is to assist teacher in adding a new Question and Choices for that question on the same page. According to Symfony documentation, I can embed a [Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/form_collections.html), so I tried embedding ChoiceType to Question form:

```
->add('answers', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => ChoiceType::class,
    'allow_add'    => true,
));
        ;
```

Code of new.html.twig page (new question):

```
<label> Choose answers : </label>
<ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{form_widget(form.answers.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
</ul>
```

But I'm getting empty select input in the browser. Please suggest what could be the perfect solution in this regard?

[image]

### Note:

I noticed that if I add

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
```

to my QuestionType I get the form with an empty select in new.html.twig

when I delete this import I get this error if I open new.html.twig :

```
 Variable "expanded" does not exist in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 38
```

but I don't have any variable in my entities called 'expanded'

**Choice Entity**

```
class Choice
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="answer", type="text")
     */
    private $answer;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="correct", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $correct;


    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ChallengeBundle\Entity\Question",inversedBy="answers")
     */
    private $question;

...
}
```

**Question Entity:**

```
class Question
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ChallengeBundle\Entity\Choice",mappedBy="question",cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $answers;

...
}
```

**Choice Type:**

```
class ChoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('answer')
            ->add('correct')

        ;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ChallengeBundle\Entity\Choice'
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a drafy system for this.. if you interest on this please let me know

Comment: Why not to use [Moodle](https://moodle.org/), the best & mostly used platform in this regard? See the [amazing stats](https://moodle.net/stats/)

Comment: Use a TextType instead of ChoiceType. You're on the right track.

Comment: ChoiceType is the form of Choice entity thank you Jonny

Comment: I notice something when I add use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType; to my questionType I get the form with an empty select when I delete this import so it will call the form of Choice entity I get this error : Variable "expanded" does not exist in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 38 but I don't having any variable in my entities called 'expanded'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your Help

I solve my problem by creating another entity It seem that symfony framework find a confusion in the name of my form `ChoiceType` and  `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType`

Answer (score 1):

**1-** If your goal is only to select existing Answers in Choice form you have to use `EntityTypeField` instead of `CollectionTypeField` in your ChoiceFormType :

```
->add('answers', EntityType::class, array(
    // query choices from this entity
    'class' => 'YourBundle:Question',

    // use the Question.name property as the visible option string
    'choice_label' => 'name',

   // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
   // 'multiple' => true,
   // 'expanded' => true,
));
```

**2-** But if you want to add new answers in your Choice form you have to keep `CollectionTypeField` as you do.

Then in you twig template when you render your Choice form you can call your Answer collection like this :

```
<ul class="answers" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.answers.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
     {% for answer in form.answers %}
          <li>{{ form_row(answer.answer) }}</li>
          <li>{{ form_row(answer.correct) }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This will display first inputs empty

Finally, as the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype) says, you have to add some javascript to read html in data-prototype attribute and dynamically add new answer forms when you click a "Add a new answer" link.

> Doc example (you just have to adapt this to your case) :
>
> ```
> var $collectionHolder;
>
> // setup an "add a tag" link
> var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a tag</a>');
> var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);
>
> jQuery(document).ready(function() {
>     // Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
>     $collectionHolder = $('ul.tags');
>
>     // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
>     $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
>
>     // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
>     // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
>     $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);
>
>     $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
>         // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
>         e.preventDefault();
>
>         // add a new tag form (see next code block)
>         addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
>     });
> });
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried your suggestion but I get also an empty select I'm trying to add new answers

Comment: I notice something when I add 
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
to my questionType I get the form with an empty select 

when I delete this import so it will call the form of Choice entity I get this error : 
Variable "expanded" does not exist in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 38

but I don't having any variable in my entities called 'expanded'

Comment: So it is normal. This solution generates empty input (and not select) to add new answers. If you want to have a select with existing answers you have to use my first point.

Comment: But it's not a good idea If there is large number of answers stored in database . the user will create many answers first then create a new question and select between answers

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent bundle for manage the symfony embedded forms and prototype. You don't need to code the js on hand and has a lot of options.  Check in [here](https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection).

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JavaScript as outlined in the [documentation section **Allowing "new" Tags with the "Prototype"**](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype).

Excerpt from the docs:

> The actual code needed to make this all work can vary quite a bit, but here's one example:
>
> ```js
> function addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
>     // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
>     var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');
>
>     // get the new index
>     var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');
>
>     // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
>     // instead be a number based on how many items we have
>     var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
>
>     // increase the index with one for the next item
>     $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);
>
>     // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
>     var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
>     $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
> }
>
> var $collectionHolder;
>
> // setup an "add a tag" link
> var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a tag</a>');
> var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);
>
> jQuery(document).ready(function() {
>     // Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
>     $collectionHolder = $('ul.tags');
>
>     // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
>     $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
>
>     // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
>     // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
>     $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);
>
>     $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
>         // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
>         e.preventDefault();
>
>         // add a new tag form (see next code block)
>         addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
>     });
> });
> ```

Comment: I added Js code as described in the documentation take a look at the picture there is 'add a tag' 
thank for your answer